# Latex would not set because it fall over things like \begin{document} and other thing

Tags: errors

I can't set my latex document. it stuck at `l.22 \begin{document}`.
When i type H in the type area under the controle output, it says:

I suspect you have forgotten a `}`, causing me to read past it when you wanted me to stop. I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious, you'd better type 'E'or 'X' now and fix your file.

I don't know what i can do, because I can not find a missing `}` somewhere.

Most time i type R, it will run trough it and than the next time it would not stop. But a next time it will.

Most of the time when it does not stop at line 22 it will, later on, at line 126 then it says something like `\newpa` or something like that. And sometimes not there but than at a other line.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). IT is difficult to help you without more information. It would be best if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows this error message. But, please try to reduce the size of the MWE -- remove any packages and sections of code that are not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post the code up here, chances are its a simple typo, perhaps you used a ) instead of a }, who knows....

Comment: well, i don't know what it can be, if i delete all the things inside the document accpted for the usepackages and the begin and end document it works perfectly. i can delete al the text expeted for the pictures and the tabulars and things but that are about 30 pictures so that is a lot already

Comment: it still are 375 lines. the error is still in the document so it is somewere in that... and if i replace all the { for new ones it are 444 and if i replace all the } for newones it are also 444 of them, so i haven't missed one

Comment: Its not as simple as counting the `{`, `}`, unless you count them _very_ carefully. For instance does you counting account for `\{`, which should not be counted.  Also, there are other things to consider such as the opening `{` and closing `}` can _not_ have alignment points (i.e., `tabular`, `array`, `align`, etc) in between, or you can't open an `{` in the start of an custom environment and close at the end of the environment definition.

Comment: Am sure there are other things to take into account. So, best thing is to keep commenting out packages/code snippets until it is small enough to post -- at which time it might be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Put the `\end{document}` few lines above the its beginning and try to find the error place.